# Accessing sql_type from Model.column_types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, postgresql-9.1

When using the `column_types` method from ActiveRecord::Base, I am able to retrieve the actual `sql_type` like so -

```
>> User.column_types.map{|k, v| [k, v.type, v.try(:sql_type)]}
[["id", :integer, "integer"],
 ["name", :string, "character varying(255)"],
 ["email", :string, "character varying(255)"],
 ["created_at", :datetime, nil],
 ["updated_at", :datetime, nil],
 ["password_digest", :string, "character varying(255)"],
 ["remember_token", :string, "character varying(255)"]]
```

Notice that the `:datetime` fields, which are implemented in the database as `timestamp without time zone`, do not provide the `sql_type` method.  However, oddly enough, it appears to exist here -

```
>> col = User.column_types['created_at']
#<ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion::Type:0x00000101a63130
    @column=..., @oid_type=..., @array=false, @name="created_at",
    @sql_type="timestamp without time zone", @null=true, @limit=nil, @precision=nil,
    @scale=nil, @type=:datetime, @default=nil, @primary=false, @coder=nil>>
```

But I can't access it!

```
>> col.sql_type
NoMethodError: undefined method `sql_type' for 
#<ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion::Type:0x00000101a63130>
```

Am I missing something here?  Or is this a bug in ActiveRecord?

Comment: Down vote?  It would be nice to understand what's wrong with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sql_type` attribute is not defined in `ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion::Type` but in its `@column` attribute.

You can access to the `sql_type` via columns like this:

```
User.columns.find{|c| c.name == 'created_at'}.sql_type
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you!  I only stumbled across this feature but couldn't find much documentation on it.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer from @baldrick, this can be done without find

```
User.columns_hash["created_at"].sql_type
```